# Можно ли как-то ожидать пока пользователь не отправит фото

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть телеграм бот на Python.И надо чтобы после команды бот должен ожидать пока пользователь не отправит фото.(Знаю метод bot.register_next_step_handler() но как его применить для ожидания фото).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def request_photo(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправьте мне фото')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, ticket_get_photo)


def get_photo(message):
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = dpath + 'user_data/{}/'.format(message.chat.id) + file_info.file_path
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    else:  # запрашиваем ещё раз, если не фото
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправьте мне фото')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_photo)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить 
`bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, ticket_get_photo #Зачем тут вы дописали к функции ticket? , row_id)`

Comment: оу, прошу прощения, я скопировал код из проекта и забыл исправить. `row_id` это переменная передаваемая как аргумент в `ticket_get_photo()`. исправил ответ