# Telegram bot, отправка прикрепленного файла через телеграмм бота на Email

Tags: python, telegram, email, бот

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть бот, который отправляет сообщения из Telegram на почту. Сообщения приходят, но не получается заставить принимать файлы(нужно отправлять фото, документы, возможно видео). Помогите пожалуйста, что нужно дописать, чтобы бот работал с файлами?

```
import telebot
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# TOKEN
TOKEN = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def process_start(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           text='Welcome!',
                           reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_email(message):
    try:
        username = "{0.username}".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me())
        fromaddr = "mail@gmail.com"
        mypass = "password"
        toaddr = "mail@mail.com"
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "Отправитель: Telegram bot"  # + str(message.chat.id)
        body = "Message: Telegram_bot \n\n" + message.text
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(fromaddr, mypass)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
        server.quit()
        bot.reply_to(message, "Message send")
    except Exception:
        bot.reply_to(message, "ERROR")
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232017/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be

Comment: Этот вопрос может помочь решить вашу проблему. Но там только про фото. Но как отправлять я не знаю. Там написано только как скачивать боту фотки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то. Если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно указать тип файлов, которые бот ожидает, например: @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video']), а дальше бот должен отправлять или текстовое сообщение или фото/документ

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615794/234134 для сохранения, а после `msg.attach`

Comment: У меня точно такая же проблема а вы уже нашли способ?